# Cant get WDS-enabled AP running on Xenial

Tags: network-bridge, hostapd

I want to set up a WDS-enabled Wifi-AP on Ubuntu Xenial with hostapd. Everytime when a 4addr-enabled client is connecting the wifi driver of the AP is crashing and the device is going down.

hostapd.conf:

```
driver=nl80211
wds_sta=1
interface=wlx803f5d2101f0
bridge=br0

hw_mode=g
ieee80211n=1

ssid=mysid
channel=3

auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=mypass
```

After hostapd is started - I add an IP to br0 and bring it up:

```
ip addr add dev br0 192.168.200.1/24
ip link set dev br0 up
```

On the client:

```
iw wlan0 set 4addr on
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip addr add dev br0 192.168.200.2/24

wpa_supplicant -b br0 -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa.conf
```

When doing the following, the wifi device on the host is crashing:

```
ip link set wlan0 master br0
ip link set dev br0 up
```

dmesg:

```
[489.721049] br0: port 1(wlx803f5d2101f0) entered forwarding state
[840.092808] device wlx803f5d2101f0 left promiscuous mode
[840.092906] br0: port 1(wlx803f5d2101f0) entered disabled state
```

wifi device on the AP:

```
Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3072 Wireless Adapter
rt2800usb
```

The same procedure with a Debian Jessie AP is working without any problems.

PS: I tried this with Debian testing and ran into the same trouble - it looks more and more like a kernel related issue ...

Comment: Ok - found a not so nice solution using parprouted - no need for 4addr mode. On the host where the wifi connection should be brigded:

Comment: `ip link add br0 type bridge
ip addr add dev br0 192.168.200.254/24
ip link set dev br0 up
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
parprouted br0 wlan0`